# Selenium - couldn't click next page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click the next button (>) and then repeat until the last page is reached. I've tried searching for solutions from similar questions but I couldn't figure out what's wrong/make it work.

Here is my code, thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/krish/Desktop/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.cnbcindonesia.com/tag/pasar-modal')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)


while True:
 try:
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class = 'icon icon-angle-right']/i")))
    if (element != 0):
        element.click()
 except TimeoutException as ex:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `xpath` looks incorrect, please try the below

***Xpath***

```
//i[@class='icon icon-angle-right']
```

***CSS Selector***

```
.icon.icon-angle-right
```

There are multiple approaches to address this issue and a couple of them are as follows:

As you intent to invoke `click()` you need to induce `WebDriverWait` in conjunction with the `WebDriverWaitWebDriverWait` for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following Locator Strategies:

**Using CSS_SELECTOR:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".icon.icon-angle-right"))).click()
```

**Using XPATH:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon icon-angle-right']"))).click()
```

*Incase the error* *...another element obscures it*... still persists first you need to induce `WebDriverWait` inconjunction with the `expected_conditions` for the `invisibility_of_element()` of the blocking element as follows:

**Using CSS_SELECTOR:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".icon.icon-angle-right")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".icon.icon-angle-right"))).click()
```

**Using XPATH:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon icon-angle-right']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon icon-angle-right']"))).click()
```

If the issue still persists you can use the `execute_script()` method as follows:

**Using CSS_SELECTOR:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".icon.icon-angle-right")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".icon.icon-angle-right"))))
```

**Using XPATH:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon icon-angle-right']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='icon icon-angle-right']"))))
```

***Note:*** : You have to import below

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait       
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By       
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: still not working, it says ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (492, 2300)

Comment: I have updated the answer hope this will solve you problem

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, finally works by using execute_script() method

```
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".icon.icon-angle-right"))))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easy with [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro)

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=False)
    baseurl = "https://www.cnbcindonesia.com/tag/pasar-modal"
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(baseurl)
    next_page = page.wait_for_selector("//i[@class='icon icon-angle-right']")
    next_page.click()
    browser.close()
```

Also if you want to paginate, you can do it with changing just URL param.
Go to page 87: https://www.cnbcindonesia.com/tag/pasar-modal/87?kanal=&tipe=